# Iterate through columns to compare each one with a specific column in Python

Tags: python, loops, pandas

I'm trying to use pandas in python to solve this problem. I have a data frame with nearly 1000 columns. For each column, I'd like to return a boolean value for a mathematical operation - specifically `Column A` - `Column n` => 0.

```
"ID" "Column A" "Column B"  "Column C"  "Column D"
"A"  100         200         300         50
"B"  75          20          74          500
```

Let's assume `Column A` is the row I'd like to use for the comparison. I would like the result to be a data frame that looks like this:

```
"ID" "Column A" "Column B"  "Column C"  "Column D"
"A"  100         False       False       True
"B"  75          True        True        False
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a `lambda` function that subtracts each column series from the target column and then tests if the result is greater than or equal to zero (`ge(0)`).

```
d = {'Column A': {'A': 100, 'B': 75},
     'Column B': {'A': 200, 'B': 20},
     'Column C': {'A': 300, 'B': 74},
     'Column D': {'A': 50, 'B': 500}}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

col = "Column A"
other_cols = [c for c in df if c != col]

>>> pd.concat([df[[col]], 
               df[other_cols].apply(lambda series: df[col].sub(series).ge(0))], axis=1)
    Column A Column B Column C Column D
ID                                     
A        100    False    False     True
B         75     True     True    False
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
c = 'Column A'
d = df.set_index('ID')
lt = d.drop(c, axis=1).lt(d[c], axis=0)
pd.concat([d[c], lt], axis=1).reset_index()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df.set_index("ID")
dd = df.apply(lambda x: x.lt(df["Column A"]))
dd["Column A"] = df["Column A"]
dd

        Column A Column B Column C Column D
ID                                     
A        100    False    False     True
B         75     True     True    False
```